# LG WebOS 3.0 TV App Exit Button Close App and

Tags: exit-code, webos, lg, smart-tv

I am developing a TV app for LG 4K TVs in webOS 3.0.

self_evaluation_checklist_3.4.xlsx lists a requirement for Exit button behavior as below.

"For webOS 3.0, pressing the EXIT button the app is completely closed and does not remain on the Recent list."

I have been searching but I haven't had any luck finding the API call to close the app completely and also removes the app from the Recent list.

All I could find is webOS.platformBack(); but that only takes back to the Home screen of the TV and doesn't close the app.

How can I close the app completely and don't list the app in the Recent list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct method ( webOS.platformBack(); ). 
At least our app uses the same method for all 3 generations of WebOS and has never been declined by LG QA Center for this.

Comment: Thank you LadyBo. I will do the same.

Comment: @LadyBo `webOS.platformBack();` function, instead of closing the app and place the App to the recent list, simulates the smart Button which opens the list of all apps at the bottom of the screen.

(WebOS.js from "https://github.com/enyojs/enyo-webos/blob/master/webOS/webOS.js")

What can i use also in order to exit the app and place it at the recent list below ?!?
Thank you.

Comment: Try read this thread - http://developer.lge.com/community/forums/RetrieveForumContent.dev?detailContsId=FC17063209 

"In the webOS TV, app closing is not supported/allowed;" 

And I particularly don't know any instruments or functions to remove it from recent apps list, unfortunately.

Comment: @user2326737, forgot to mention you in a comment before.

Answer (score 1):

To exit the app and leave it in the Recent list I used the following:

```
const APPLICATION_MANAGER_SERVICE = 'luna://com.webos.applicationManager';
const TV_APP_ID = 'com.webos.app.livetv';

function sendAppToBackground() {
  webOS.service.request(APPLICATION_MANAGER_SERVICE, {
    method: 'launch',
    parameters: { id: TV_APP_ID },
    onSuccess(response) {
      if (response.returnValue === false) {
        console.error(`Error sending Application to background and bringing TV Application with ID ${TV_APP_ID} to the foreground.`);
        forciblyExitApp();
      }
    },
    onFailure(error) {
      console.error(error);
      forciblyExitApp();
    },
  });
}

function forciblyExitApp() {
  window.close();
}
```